# Simpler invariant using md5sum

Tags: c, discrete-mathematics, md5sum

I would like to use invariants to distinguish mathematical objects. I have them and they are formed by one sequence int[N] of integers. The invariant is very powerful and useful but it has one disadvantage: It is bulky because N is large.

What I want is to have a simpler invariant and using **md5sum** seems appropriate. Some distinct invariants may be put together but that is not a problem because they are anyway
just invariants and expected to be rare. Is there a C interface to md5sum for such a list of integers? That sounds a standard requirement, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard md5 C library, but there are lots of free implementations out there.  Search for "md5 c" on Google and the [first link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Md5.c&ei=ZmF_T8PKOIXXiAKzlZy1Aw&usg=AFQjCNEu3k_qiRjgKfQ-l002OXCUYqSaXA&sig2=S71aEwCFqAd-0I5NPyL1Tw) contains an implementation.